# Auto emails when date in list data matches today's date

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to create an auto-generated email when date in the one of columns in the list matched today's date.

Comment: can you add more specifications? like version of sharepoint? if you want it do in OOTB actions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SharePoint online it is now a OOTB Flow. Another option could be a timer job in Azure that checks the dates in the list against today.

If you are using on premises a scheduled timer job (C# or PowerShell) could be an option

In both cases you can use either CAML or Search to locate the items where the date field matches today (be careful about the timezone issue)